# Headphone isn't detected by Win7 but will on Ubuntu (on dualboot)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio, headphones

I got a computer that is on dualboot (Win7 and Ubuntu (14.04)).

Here is my problem. When I am on Ubuntu and I plug my headphones on, it works. BUT, when I'm on Win7, the HP aren't detected. I get no notification as such as "new device detected".

Headphones:

- SONY Casque DJ pivotant MDR-V55.
- Work with Win8 (other computer), Win7 (another PC), Ubuntu 14.04 on this computer.
- Gold plated jack connector.

PC:

- EliteBook 8540w
- DualBoot Win7 Pro / Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got the correct sound card drivers installed, and is it functioning correctly, according to device manager?

Comment: We need a bit more information before we can help you. Which headphones do you have? Brand and type? How are the connected? Through soundcard using a jack plug, or through USB? Have they worked before? If they are USB headphones, do you get a notification of new hardware found when plugging them in? As you can see lots of questions with way too many answers.

Comment: @RowlandShaw The sound card is working correctly. The spkeakers intergrated in the PC are functionning.